# How to extract a deeply nested value from a module result into a variable for later tasks?

Tags: ansible

In this instance I'm using the uri module to smoketest an API deployment.  The flow is:

1. Attempt to log test user in and capture JWT token
2. If #1 fails register new user
3. If #2 fired simulate clicking the verify user email link
4. If #3 fired log the new test user in and capture JWT token

In #1 or #4 I'd like to assign the JWT from the result to a variable for later use.  Something like:

```
- name: log user in
  uri:
    url: "{{ api_url }}/user"
    method: post
    body_format: json
    body:
      email: "{{ email }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
  assign: 
    jwt: {{ response.json.data.jwt }}
```

As if `assign` were a thing.  I could `register: session` and use `{{ session.json.data.jwt}}` a hundred times in the rest of the smoke tests without it but it would be so much cleaner if I could mutate a play scoped variable, perhaps defined at the top of the playlist.

Comment: I also find myself instinctively looking for this feature quite often. I think your best bet is a `set_fact` straight after the task though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from @matt-p in the comments - use set_fact.  Thanks.

I wanted to show off how well this works on a REST API.  Notice how we can later access keys from the returned JSON with a simple `{{ user.email }}` and use the JWT token with `headers: 
 jwt={{ user.jwt }}`

```
- name: Login and get JWT session
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}/users/login"
    body_format: json
    body:
      email: "{{ email }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    method: POST
    status_code: [200]
  register: user_login

- name: Assign user variable to user_login results
  set_fact:
    user: "{{ user_login.json.data }}"

- name: Create a post
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}/users/{{ user.id }}/posts"
    body_format: json
    method: POST
    headers: jwt={{ user.jwt }}
    body:
      content: >
          My name is {{ user.firstName }} and you
          can email me at {{ user.email }}
    status_code: [201]
  register: post_creation
```